# Running Hadoop job as another user

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm running Hadoop 1.2.1 and it is configured for user hadoopuser. I'm trying to submit a job from my windows machine and here is a problem because on my windows machine I'm no longer a hadoopuser, so I'm getting:

```
security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException
```

Is there any way that I could submit a job for hadoop user from my windows machine?

UPDATE: the stack trace:

```
 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:windowsuser cause:org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=windowsuser, access=WRITE, inode="mapred":hadoopuser:supergroup:rwxr-xr-x
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=windowsuser, access=WRITE, inode="mapred":hadoopuser:supergroup:rwxr-xr-x
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.mkdirs(DFSClient.java:1459)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirs(DistributedFileSystem.java:362)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:942)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:910)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1353)
    at com.rf.mapreduce.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:40)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the entire error log ?

I think your problem is because you didn't clean the output file when you change the user.

try :

```
hdfs dfs -rmr /home/hadoop/your-output-dir
```

the path depend on your HDFS implementation.

Comment: I added the stack trace to the original question. There is no output folder as the job has not been executed and the output folder has not been created.

Comment: The problem is usually that mapreduce is trying to create something in the user dir, in your case /user/windowsuser. Since the user "windowsuser" doesn't have write privileges to /mapred, this fails. If you create your user's home directory in hdfs and chown it to the right user, you'll probably get past this error.